# SQLBindCol()/SQLFetch() returns trailing spaces

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

ALL,

I'm trying to create a program that connects to MS SQL Server (2012). The program will execute some SELECT queries.

When I try to use the code like this:

```
ret = SQLBindCol( stmt_tableProp, 25, SQL_C_WCHAR, &comments, 225, &cbComment );
ret = SQLFetch( stmt_tableProp );
```

the value in the "comment" variable will be:

```
"This is a comment            "
```

whereas I expect it to be:

```
"This is a comment"
```

I presume I need to set some option on the connection.

Surprisingly enough trying to execute this same code on mySQL and PostgreSQL does not produce this result. I get what to be expected with both unixODBC and iODBC.

Am I right? If yes, which one and how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me to be a case of either the underlying column being or treating the column as char vs varchar.  Char will always be padded to the width of the column

Comment: yes, the field is defined as "char(254)" in the CREATE TABLE() statement. So should I use varchar(254)?

Comment: I tried changing the field type to be varchar(254), but the code still returns the string with the trailing spaces.

Comment: @Igor: Did you delete the value and re-inserted the value without spaces after changing the column type?

Comment: @erg, the value didn't contain any spaces after text. But let me update the record just to be absolutely sure

Comment: @erg, I updated the record and now everything is OK. I guess MS SQL Server pads data but when querying inside Management Studio cuts off spaces

Comment: @Igor = yes, SSMS does somewhat mess with the display of text, for example it will strip out carriage-returns also.